# knockout.js ASP.NET data-bind to dropdownlist (Visual Studio 2008)

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, data-binding, knockout.js

I'm attempting to data-bind a value to an ASP.NET DropDownList but the server complains that it doesn't recognize the data-bind attribute:

```
<%=Html.DropDownList("accountSiteInstanceId", ViewData["degreePrograms"] as SelectList, new { @data-bind = "value: DegreeProgramId" } ) %>
```

I get the following error:
Compiler Error Message: CS0746: Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Comment: you can create a custom html helper for this

Comment: Cool -- any chance you might be able point me in the direction of an example?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is the dash. Use dictionary based notation:

```
<%= Html.DropDownList("accountSiteInstanceId", ViewData["degreePrograms"] as SelectList, new Dictionary<string, object>
                {
                        {"data-bind", 
                        "DegreeProgramId"}
                }) %>
```

Answer (score 4):

change the dash into an underscore and it will convert it back to dash on runtime.